# Old winforms application showing strange simbols in textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have an old Winforms application (VB.NET) which is showing very strange simbols in a textbox when i type regular characters since the last Windows 10 update.

Font is Microsoft Sans Serif 8.25 Italic

[image]

This corresponds to "abc"

In a non updated Windows 10 computer works fine. Quite strange. Any hint on what is going on? Thanks

Comment: What's the keyboard language?

Comment: the language is spanish (es_ES)

Comment: Microsoft Sans Serif does not exist anymore, it always gets substituted.  You got a Tamil non-Unicode font for some reason.  How hot is it outside?   Removing the font would be the most obvious thing to do, ask about fixing the font mapper at superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

The problem was this font style line. The empty string was causing to fallback to this symbols font:

`New System.Drawing.Font("", 8.25F, FontStyle.Italic)`

Comment: By the way, these are zodiac/astrological symbols. You probably have such font on your system, which for some reason has been selected as a fallback for empty font name.